# JavaFX binding between TextField and a property

Tags: java, binding, javafx, textfield

If you create a binding between a JavaFX TextField and a property, then this binding is invalidated on every keystroke, which causes a change to the text.

If you have a chain of bindings the default behavior could cause problems, because in the middle of the editing values may be not valid.

Ok, I know I could create an uni-directional binding from the property to the textfield and register a change listener to get informed when the cursor leaves the field and update the property manually if necessary.

Is there an easy, elegant way to change this behavior so that the binding is only invalidated when the editing is complete, e.g. when the cursor leaves the field?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Note that as of JavaFX8u40 this answer is obsolete. Refer to the `TextFormatter` approach in [clartaq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236058/2189127)

I think you've pretty much described the only way to do it. Here's about the cleanest way I can see to implement it (using Java 8, though it's easy enough to convert the lambdas back to be JavaFX 2.2 compatible if you need):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
    public class CommitBoundTextField extends Application {
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            TextField tf1 = new TextField();
            createCommitBinding(tf1).addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
                System.out.printf("Text 1 changed from \"%s\" to \"%s\"%n", oldText, newText));
            TextField tf2 = new TextField();
            createCommitBinding(tf2).addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
                System.out.printf("Text 2 changed from \"%s\" to \"%s\"%n", oldText, newText));
            VBox root = new VBox(5, tf1, tf2);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 100);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        
        private StringBinding createCommitBinding(TextField textField) {
            StringBinding binding = Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> textField.getText());
            textField.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, evt -> binding.invalidate());
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isFocused)-> {
                if (! isFocused) binding.invalidate();
            });
            return binding ;
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I am a little late with a response, but thought this might be useful to someone.

When using `TextField`s, I often attach a `TextFormatter` to help validate entries. You can attach a listener to the formatters' `valueProperty`. That property is updated when the text is committed, rather than on every keystroke.

Here's an example of what I am talking about using a `TextField` specialized for integer inputs. When you make edits in the text field, the changes will be reflected in the `Label` when you tap Enter, lose focus by clicking the button, switch to a different window, and so on.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

class IntTextField extends TextField {

    private final IntegerProperty value;
    TextFormatter<Integer> formatter;

    public double getValue() {
        return value.getValue();
    }

    public void setValue(int newValue) {
        value.setValue(newValue);
    }

    public IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public StringBinding getStringBinding () {
        return value.asString();
    }

    IntTextField(int initValue) {
        value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(initValue);
        setText(initValue + "");
        formatter = new TextFormatter(new IntegerStringConverter(), initValue);
        formatter.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Integer> obs,
                Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) -> value.setValue(newValue));
        setTextFormatter(formatter);
    }

    IntTextField() {
        this(0);
    }
}

public class TFBindingDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("TFBindingDemo");
        IntTextField intTextField = new IntTextField(12345);
        intTextField.setMaxWidth(150);
        Label label = new Label("Type in the TextField");
        label.textProperty().bind(intTextField.getStringBinding());
        Button removeFocusButton = new Button("Click Here to Remove Focus");
        VBox root = new VBox(20, intTextField, label, removeFocusButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 325, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```